# Android RelativeLayout : Text getting clipped

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I think an image will explain this far better than words. The screenshot is from the layout viewer thingy in Intellij, but this happens on device as well. I want the cut off text to not be displayed at all. Is this possible?

[image: Clipped Text]

Comment: can you post your layout code

Comment: I have put the relevant layout properties I am using in the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
   ....
   android:lines="2"
```

or:

```
<TextView
   ....
   android:maxLines="2"
```

First option sets exact number of lines for your text view, second options sets the maximum number.

Comment: I have thought of this. Setting maxLines to 2 does indeed work. But I wonder what will happen in case the user's font size settings are different from mine. Nothing stops the second line from being clipped in case my user selects different/larger font.

Comment: There can be 2 solutions: 1) specify font size in "dp", making it settings-independent; 2) put "website" textView below "description" textView, without aligning it to image bottom.